# Identifying that a Voip conversation is happening in android

Tags: android, voip

Is there any way to identify that a Voip conversation is happening in android?

I have an app that needs to know whether any conversation is happening now  through Voip. Never mind if it's Skype, Viber, WhatsApp or whatever.

I know that there are many different protocols for Voip, some of them proprietary.  But I wonder if there is some clever way to do it.

Comment: Well you can get running task pre lollipop version and in lollipop you can get running process.

Comment: Can you please give more details about what you are offering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Profile the bandwidth.

- Find an API that lets you monitor incoming/outgoing bandwidth on a per-application basis (I don't know android but this is possible in windows and unix)
- Check each application and write heuristics to classify their bandwidth usage
- VOIP will have significant pattern, You'll have to watch it, but it will intuitively look similar to this

  - consistent amount of data being sent or received (note: test this with several VOIP solutions, and scale it - compression may vary)
  - usually doing mostly sending and mostly receiving (one side talks at once while the other just sends Acks)
  - sending and receiving swaps at a known interval (like a conversation)
  - maybe write a neural network if you have hundreds of recordings of conversations/non-conversations/borderline to train it with.
  - Etc ... you get the idea. Google 'detect a conversation' for more (couple good studies near the top). Note these portend access to the data stream; you will only be able to see data usage unless the VOIP is stupid enough not to encrypt or somehow let you MITM them.

Notes:

- if something other than a conversation is going on, or there is noise, this may fail
- no program has to identify itself as VOIP. Assuming you're monitoring employees they could download something obscure or bespoke to fool you. And data should be encrypted. So this is your only hope.
- Possible to fool this by faking sending extra data. Not likely ... why would a program waste bandwidth?
- If the users want to fool you into thinking they *are* talking - e.g., they are your telemarketers - why not mandate what they use? You would probably want to anyway so you can record for legal purposes.

Comment: Thanks!  btw, regarding some of your notes : I'm not spying on my users. I'm trying to give them something. The only one who will get fooled is the very user who tries to fool the system.

Comment: That's cool to know. I would not dis you if you had been spying ... if you're paying employees to work and you own the device, (yet let them d/l apps), nothing wrong with not throwing money away! Actually this ups the ante a bit, the quality of your product depends on accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that will give current running application

```
ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

    List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> tasks = manager.getRunningAppProcesses();

    Log.i("current_running_app",tasks.get(0).processName);
```

Comment: Thanks! But how would that help me identify whether the user is in a voip conversation?

Comment: well this will be useful when you have that information in hand. Also this ,links may help you                                                          http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28940142/getting-socket-connection-error-while-connection-socket-bluetooth-barcode-scanne    And  http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/24084/list-of-open-ports-on-android

Comment: I would advise against using `getRunningAppProcesses()`, as the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningAppProcesses()) state **This method is only intended for debugging or building a user-facing process management UI**.

Answer (score 0):

You can detect incoming calls using this:

http://karanbalkar.com/2014/02/detect-incoming-call-and-call-hangup-event-in-android/

I also found another SO answer that maybe can help you:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22904362/1723525

Using the [SipAudioCall.Listener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/sip/SipAudioCall.Listener.html)

Comment: Thanks. But I'm quite aware to the two links you gave: Your first solution is not for Voip. It's for normal conversation. Your second solution is for implementing Voip yourself. Not for identifying others.